# python `getattr` like function that accepts dotted string

Tags: python, oop, object, attributes

I would like to implement a function which is similar to `getattr` but will accept a dotted string and traverse through each attributes.

```
def getattr_multiple_level(obj, attr_string):
    attr_names = attr_string.split('.')
    next_level = obj
    for attr_name in attr_names:
        next_level = getattr(next_level, attr_name)
    return next_level

class Test():
    def make_name(self, pre, suffix=""):
        return str(pre) + "_my_office_" + suffix


p = Test()
p.room = Test()
p.room.office = Test()

attr = getattr_multiple_level(p, 'room.office.make_name')
```

Is there already a built-in way to do this? Or what improvements can be made in above code to handle all possible exceptions and edge cases?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is "build-in way". You can use property decorator. https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property

```
class Author(object):

    def __init__(self, full_name):
        self.full_name = full_name


class Book(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    @property
    def author(self):
        return Author("Philip Kindred Dick")

class Library(object):

    @property
    def book_ubik(self):
        return Book("ubik")


library = Library()

print(library.book_ubik.name)
print(library.book_ubik.author.full_name)
```

Result:

```
grzegorz@grzegorz-GA-78LMT-USB3:~/tmp$ python3 propery_test.py 
ubik
Philip Kindred Dick
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is functional, but there's room for conciseness. Here's a snippet that worked for me:

```
from functools import reduce

def safe_getattr(obj, attr, default=None):
    """
    It return value of dotted attributes
    Example:
        self.safe_getattr(obj, "key_pointer.data_type", None)
        returns - "duration"
    """
    try:
        return reduce(getattr, attr.split("."), obj)
    except AttributeError:
        return default
```